# LEFT_SUBFIELD error with Mongodb even when the element is an object

Tags: mongodb

I have the query:

```
db.Sets.update({_id: "NxQRkA9hJ6rbjhoEN", "cards.set":"Theros"}, {"$set":{"cards.$.set_code": "THS"}});
```

My data set is something like this:

```
{
"name" : "THS",
"cards" : [
    {
        "name" : "Omenspeaker",
        "set" : "Theros",
        "set_code" : "THS",
        "id" : "370735"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Sedge Scorpion",
        "set" : "Theros",
        "set_code" : "THS",
        "id" : "370765"
    },
    ]
}
```

Here is a slightly more complete set of data, copied and pasted from mongo command line:
http://pastebin.com/ix5QaQP3

And I get an error like this:

```
LEFT_SUBFIELD only supports Object: cards.0. not: 2
```

I read a bunch on this and struggled with it for 40 minutes before giving up and just writing a script to update my data instead. Still I'm wonder why it wouldn't work, and how I was supposed to do it.

Comment: you're probably using one of those shady mappers? I've never seen `LEFT_SUBFIELD` in mongodb...

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10244921/383478

Comment: I'm using mongoDB 2.4.6. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the key-value pairs with **empty** keys from your data set.

MongoDB throws the `LEFT_SUBFIELD only supports Object:` error when it encounters an empty key in the subdocument being updated.

Your example data is fine but your pastebin data is different. You have an empty key-value pair (`"":""`) in each of your subdocuments.

From your pastebin data:

```
{
    "name" : "THS",
    "cards" : [
            {
                    "name" : "Abhorrent Overlord",
                    ...
                    "legality_Peasant" : "",
                    "legality_Pauper" : "",
                    "" : "" <------ this line causes the issue
            },
            ...
```